# React web app spread across multiple browser windows / dual screen app

Tags: reactjs

A client has tasked me with refactoring their React app to support multiple screens. I have some ideas on how to approach this, and would like to get some feedback to see if I am on the right track.

**The problem:**

- We have a relatively complex React app, and the client feels that splitting the app across multiple windows will make for a better UX.
- As example of this split-screen set up, imagine that window 1 shows some data, and window 2 contains UI elements that allow you to filter that data. In this manner, the app is split across 2 windows.
- (The 2 browser windows is a hard constraint imposed by the product owner. Other options like grid layout managers are not considered.)

**The solution (so far):**

We need to share state across two browser windows. To do so, we can use:

- Local storage to keep track of state and use [StorageEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StorageEvent) listeners to coordinate state changes between the two windows.
- We can also use some of the web APIs designed to pass data between windows including: shared web worker, broadcast channels, and `window.postmessage()`. I learned about these in Blake Zimmerman's presentation [here, PDF ~2mb](https://github.com/blakezimmerman/multi-window-react/blob/master/SLIDES.pdf).
- This framework - [neo.mjs](https://github.com/neomjs/neo), which uses web workers. I would rather not abstract the low-level details to a framework, because I am not familiar with web workers myself yet.

**The question:**

1. Is there something I am missing? Are there other tools I can use to share state between windows? Any good articles I can read?
2. I am also having trouble visualizing how to structure the React app to account for multiple displays. The best I could come up with is something like this:

```
<Main>
  {isComponentAShown && <ComponentA/>}
  {isComponentBShown && <ComponentB/>}
</Main>
```

where `isComponent_X_Shown` dictate which components the browser window should be displaying at any one time. These boolean flags will be part of the state shared by the two browser windows. Is there a better way to organize the App layouts to account for dual screen?

Thank you!